# Google Talk on Samsung Galaxy S II

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, google-talk

I bought a Samsung Galaxy S II, and it comes with the IM application for instant messaging, but the only messengers available are Windows Live Messenger and Yahoo! Messenger, and I couldn't find any Google Talk application on the market.

How can use Google Talk?

Comment: The US-carriers versions of the GS2 come with Google Talk, it is named "Talk". I am not sure about the European version.

Comment: I've got the brazilian version. After a few months, the IM app got an update that allowed it to communicate with GTalk users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow's absolutely right, but if you want to try another messenger that supports GTalk you could try [Meebo](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.meebo), [eBuddy](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ebuddy.android), or [Trillian](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ceruleanstudios.trillian.android).  There are others, of course, but those are the ones I've tried that work well.

Answer (score 6):

There is no Google Talk app within the Market. Google Talk is more or less wired to the Android release. It's usually an icon in the app drawer simply named "Talk".

Your phone seems pretty locked down by the carrier (or somebody else). If it really came without Google Talk, which would be pretty uncommon, your only chance is to install the [Google Talk apk manually](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1117883).